# sed regular expression does not return expected results

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am trying to search for files which matches following expression with sed

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}\s{1,5}\"
```

after executing

```
sed -e '/\([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}\s{1,5}\"\)/!d'
```

it does not give expected results

could one please assist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sed you need to escape the curly brackets for repetitions, try the following:

```
sed -e '/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,10\}\s\{1,5\}\"\)/!d'
```

Here is a nice reference page on the [sed regex syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions).

If this doesn't work, try replacing `\s` with `[ \t\r\n]`